# Is the rank of an elliptic curve with CM even?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve which has CM and $K$ the imaginary quadratic field in which $End(E)$ is an order. I have 3 questions, which are somehow related to each other:

1. If one considers $E(K)$ as a module over $End(E)$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$, and $E(K)$ has rank $n$ over $End(E)$, will it have rank $2n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$?
2. Is it true that the rank of the Mordell-Weil group (i.e. rank of $E(K)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module) of such a curve is even? (of course, second question is clearly true if the answer to the first one is affirmative)
3. If questions 1) and 2) fail and $E(K)$ has rank $2$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, how can I test if it has rank $1$ as an $End(E)$ module?

All the examples that I have come accross in Cremona's tables and another sample of $500$ curves tested with Magma satisfy the second assertion (it is maybe worth pointing out that almost all of these examples were curves which can be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: Side comment related to the field of definition remark at the end:  if $E$ has CM by an order in $K$ and can be defined over $K$, then in fact $j(E)$ is in $\mathbb Q$ and so $E$ an be defined over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $A=E(K)/E(K)_{\text{tors}}$ is a free Abelian group, and also
a module over an order $\mathfrak O$ in a the quadratic field $K$. Then $A$ must have
even rank: $A\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Q=A\otimes_{\mathfrak O}K$
has dimension over $\Bbb Q$ twice the dimension over $K$.